# self.view.bounds.size.width return wrong value

Tags: objective-c, iphone, bounds

I am facing a very strange problem now. Getting `[[self view] bounds].size.width` always `320` it's not changing according to the device. iPhone 5, 6 & 6 Plus for all it's return `320.000000` in below all methods.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%f", [[self view] bounds].size.width);
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%f", [[self view] bounds].size.width);
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%f", [[self view] bounds].size.width);
}
```

Output

```
2015-02-11 14:48:03.274 MyApp[2948:86285] 320.000000 
2015-02-11 14:48:03.274 MyApp[2948:86285] 320.000000
2015-02-11 14:48:03.783 MyApp[2948:86285] 320.000000
```

Even the splash screen are also there.

How can I get actual size of the view?

Comment: If your `view.bounds.size.width` is `320` then `view`'s bounds is 320 points wide. Perhaps your view doesn't take up the full width of the device.

Comment: [Why your view isn't taking up the full width of the device?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28448653/1603072)

Comment: @AaronBrager this view is the view of viewController. So I am not sure how to take the full width of the device.

Comment: Its bit unclear. Can u paste some code?

Comment: Which method are u using to check screen size?

Comment: @GajendraKChauhan Please check my updated question. This happen for all the devices.

Comment: @TapasPal You will also get height 480. Right? Bcoz when u created view controller ur default xib was also 320*480 at that time. Also if u select xib and resize it to 4.7 or 4.0 u will get a width accordingly.

Comment: @GajendraKChauhan Why?? this should be dynamic. Means the bounds should be changed according to the device not what I have selected in xib file.

Comment: For those who are putting vote to close this question. Can you please give a solution??

Answer (score 18):

Use

```
NSLog(@"%f", [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width);
```

instead of

```
NSLog(@"%f", [[self view] bounds].size.width);
```

It gives u expected w/h.

Comment: Yes, it's working fine. But why my view not giving right value while it's taking the full screen on each device.

Comment: I just wanted to know while my view taking the full screen on each device then why it's width is like static 320.??

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes all you need is to do such things on a **main** thread.

For me,

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //access to the frame/bounds
}
```

Is worked then directly accessing the frame/bound.

Comment: I have a special case where I tried everything I can: Placing codes in viewDidAppear, layoutSubviews, etc but still receive the wrong frame/bounds value. But your suggestion of accessing the values in the main thread solves the issue for me. Thanks @Hemang!

Comment: Glad to know that this help!

Answer (score 9):

If you try to read `[[self view] bounds].size.width`value in `-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` you will see that it will show the right value.

In `- (void)viewDidLoad` `[[self view] bounds].size.width` will show you exact design you have in .xib file.

See below sample and NSLog results.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSLog(@"%f",[[self view] bounds].size.width);

}
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog(@"%f",[[self view] bounds].size.width);
    [testIndicator startAnimatingInView:self.view];
}
```

Respectively results are:

```
2016-02-17 19:00:47.519 xxxxx[16107:504629] 320.000000
2016-02-17 19:00:47.521 xxxxx[16107:504629] 414.000000
```

Comment: You can see in my question that for didLoad, willAppear, didAppear i use this.

Comment: Thank you @icloud. You just solved my issue. I was trying to get it in viewDidLoad

Comment: How to get the correct width in viewDidLoad @icould?

Answer (score 3):

It's happening as you're missing the *launch* file for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus.
Try one of these two approaches :

1. In Xcode, go to your target, general and add the launch screen ("Main") file there.
2. If you are using asset catalogs, go to the LaunchImages asset catalog and add the new launch images for the two new iPhones. You may need to right-click and choose "Add New Launch Image" to see a place to add the new images.

The iPhone 6 (Retina HD 4.7) requires a portrait launch image of `750 x 1334`.
The iPhone 6 Plus (Retina HD 5.5) requires both portrait and landscape images sized as `1242 x 2208` and `2208 x 1242` respectively.

Comment: No, launch screen are there.

Comment: @TapasPal: then add one !! Xcode by default provides, "Main.storyboard" file. Try to use it as mentioned in 1st step.

Comment: I am not using storyboard.

Comment: Ho-ly-sh-t !!! This is crazy man! As soon as I added that launch screen for iPhone 6 everything was back to normal. This is super weird!!!
Thanks dude!

Comment: Yes, definitely you have to avoid launching through images sources and set a launch screen file, then you can get the right mainScreen bounds for each device.

Comment: Also I'm not using storyboard, but use one for the LaunchImage. When i push a controller it gets resized and it is visible for user (it is blinking). the solution above didnt work... any update?

Answer (score 3):

It's absolutely necessary that you add a launch image of proper size for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus. Otherwise these devices will stretch a 320 points width to full screen. Thus you get 320 reported as width. With launch image you'll get 475 or 414 reported as width.

Comment: Thank you! Took me hours to realise this. Is it documented?

Answer (score 3):

Use`- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews` instead.
Look at this: [Managing View Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/DefiningYourSubclass.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
Use **viewDidLayoutSubviews** method

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    print("Size of View: \(view.bounds)")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you please do a test by simply creating a new test project and just writing below three log statements inside `viewDidLoad` method of `ViewController`, like this -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"screens = %@", [UIScreen screens]);
    NSLog(@"self.frame= %@", NSStringFromCGRect([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]));
    NSLog(@"self.view.frame= %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
}
```

Build and Run - You'll get the actual resolution of the device/screen/view

Sample output-

```
2015-02-11 12:45:19.116 Test[1558:87057] screens = (
    "<UIScreen: 0x7ff0b970bcc0; bounds = {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x7ff0b961b500; size = 750.000000 x 1334.000000>>"
)
2015-02-11 12:45:19.117 Test[1558:87057] self.frame= {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}
2015-02-11 12:45:19.117 Test[1558:87057] self.view.frame= {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am also facing the same issue which you faced. I think your viewcontroller is 320 width. After your view load, call one method after some delay and then get corrent view's frame or view's bound. You get the right frame.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(getMyFrame) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
-(void)getMyFrame
{
    NSLog(@"%f", [[self view] bounds].size.width);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should better rely on the Screen bounds for several reasons. They'd return exact value for different devices.

```
NSLog(@"Width: %f Height: %f"
      ,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width
      ,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%f", [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width);
    NSLog(@"%f", [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
}
```